# Objective-C: How can I detect http URL's in a string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, cocoa-touch, nsstring

Let's assume I have the string:

```
"I love visiting http://www.google.com"
```

How can I detect the token, http://www.google.com?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590440/how-can-i-extract-a-url-from-a-sentence-that-is-in-a-nsstring which gives several options dependant on target iOS version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to detect http links using Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002645/unable-to-detect-http-links-using-regex)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [`NSDataDetectors`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html) These were added in iOS4 and are quite useful. You want to create a data detector with the `NSTextCheckingTypeLink` and let it do its thing.

```
NSString *testString = @"Hello http://google.com world";
NSDataDetector *detect = [[NSDataDetector alloc] initWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [detect matchesInString:testString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [testString length])];
NSLog(@"%@", matches);
```

Comment: Can you use custom detectors too? EDIT: I see that it's just a subclass of NSRegulatExpression. Hehe, silly me.

Comment: FWIW, not only iOS 4+, OS X 10.7 knows them now, too.

Comment: As a matter of fact I wrote that example in 10.7

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. My issue was that I was using a bold font for links on a UIWebView, so once the built in data detector injected the link tags it would update the web view content size and screw up my size calculations elsewhere. Doing the data detection myself allowed me to have it happen precisely when I wanted it to!

Comment: Its a great answer, but I just found it cannot support many new domains, such as :  .xyz, .party ... :(

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
-(BOOL)textIsUrl:(NSString*)someString {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES ^[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\\+.~#?&//=]{2,256}\\.[a-z]{2,4}\\b(\\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\\+.~#?&//=]*)?$"];

    [predicate evaluateWithObject:someString];
}
```